# Zend DB Select : ORDER BY FIELD('id',some_array) - how?

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, zend-db

How would you write the following query in Zend framework?

`SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY FIELD(field_name, 'Small','Medium','Large');`

I just need the "Order by" part :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

What about this:

```
      $db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();

      $select = $db->select();

      $select->from('table_name')
              ->order(new Zend_Db_Expr("FIELD(field_name, 'Small','Medium','Large')"));


      var_dump($select->assemble());
```

Results in:

```
string 'SELECT `table_name`.* FROM `table_name` ORDER BY FIELD(field_name, 'Small','Medium','Large')' (length=92)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$select->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('FIELD(field_name, 'Small','Medium','Large')'));
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should do:

```
$db = Zend_Db::factory( ...options... );
$select = $db->select()
 ->from(table_name)
 ->order(new Zend_Db_Expr("FIELD(field_name, 'Small','Medium','Large')")));
```