# Magento Load Collection Using Order By

Tags: magento

My query is generating from magento collection is

```
$userModel = Mage::getSingleton('user/user')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('user_id', array('in' => array($User_Id)));

SELECT `main_table`.user_name FROM `user_table` AS `main_table` WHERE (user_id IN('1', '3', '2'));
```

I want to use this query:

```
SELECT `main_table`.user_name FROM `user_table` AS `main_table` WHERE (user_id IN('1', '3', '2')) ORDER BY FIELD(user_id , 1,3,2);
```

So that it will display the user name in the same order as ID's are input.
i.e. "1,3,2"

Which method is used in Magento to load collection using `ORDER BY`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Moreover, if 'Order By' is not possible in Magento collection, is it advisable to write our own custom query if there are multiple collections to load and modify them according to the custom requirement ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158424/how-to-add-order-by-when-loading-a-magento-model

Comment: @seanbreeden function setOrder($attribute, $dir='desc') uses ASC or DESC parameter while what I am discussing is about my sql function which is ORDER BY FIELD (http://jonahellison.com/mysql-order-by-field-group_concat).

So is it possible to use above mysql function to order by data according to custom need usign Magento Collection ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get `Zend_Db_Select` from `Collection` and then add order to `Zend_Db_Select` like this question:

[Zend DB Select : ORDER BY FIELD('id',some_array) - how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612037/zend-db-select-order-by-fieldid-some-array-how)

Comment: what difference it would make to use above code and use magento custom query code ?

How can we execute multiple records using fetch() method in magento ?